# Should there be separate tags for transferring data?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently three tags which seem to me to have the same purpose transferring data between web-apps and desktop software:

[[import]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import) [[export]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) [[transfer]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer)

Should these really have separate tags, or is there a subtle semantic distinction I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

I might want to ***export*** emails from my Gmail account and ***import*** them into my SuperOnlineEmailManager account. Now, if very few people use the SuperOnlineEmailManager service, then I might want to ask two separate questions so that the first gets answered even if the second doesn't get answers:

- Q1: How can I export my emails from Gmail? *Tags:* `gmail`, `export`, `emails`
- Q2: How can I import my emails into SOEM? *Tags:* `soem`, `import`, `emails`

However, I might also want to ***transfer*** my list of contacts/friends from my Gmail account to my Facebook account, since Facebook provides a tool for Gmail to Facebook:

- Q: Why am I having problems transferring my Gmail contacts into my Facebook friends? *Tags:* `gmail`, `facebook`, `facebook-friends`, `gmail-contacts`

Comment: In practice a lot of the questions are for transfering data from one service to another, no matter what the tags. Wanting to export data to transfer it also assumes that the solution is exporting it to a raw format.

Comment: I think you're missing the tag "transfer" in your last question.