# Burninate [data]?

Tags: discussion, tags

**UPDATE:** At present there are NO Qs tagged [data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) - though it is certain to rear its ugly head again unless *blacklisted*.

---

On Stack Overflow it has been accepted that the tag [data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) is hopelessly too broad to serve a tag's purpose and after a massive struggle, was eventually blacklisted there.

**Are circumstances here enough different to justify its retention?**

Other tags with "data" in them:

[data-validation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-validation)
[data-visualization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization)
[data-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)
[google-data-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio)

Related: [Should there be separate tags for transferring data?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113/should-there-be-separate-tags-for-transferring-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, jeez, what a mess.

Yes, that's a worthless tag. It's not conveying any useful information on any of the questions I see. And it has no context unless also paired with a tag for a web app.

Yes, it should be burninated.

In some cases, it can be replaced with one of these:

- [migrate-data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-data)
- [data-liberation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-liberation)
- [data-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)
- [data-validation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-validation)
- [data-visualization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization)

Comment: That's fine. Just don't overload the front page.